# Jacobi series for Bessel's function

Tags: bessel-functions

Using Jacobi series, prove the following

${J_0}^2+{J_1}^2+{J_2}^2+\cdots=1$

My trial:

$\cos(x\sin θ)=J_0+2J_2\cos(2θ) +2J_4\cos(4θ)+\cdots$

$\sin(x\sinθ)=2\big(J_1\sin(θ) +J_3\sin(3θ)+J_5\sin(5θ)+\cdots\big)$

Squaring both equations and adding them is what I thought we are supposed to do but in this is not enough to solve this equality. How do i proceed from here

Comment: The ()'s are oddly placed, please fix that.

Comment: Weird equations, there is no $x$ on the RHS.

Answer (score 0):

Let both of the Jaccobi series then square both of the equations.
Now, first take the $\cos^2$ series and apply integration with limits $0$ to $\pi$.
which then gives a result of an even number, and then take the second series and repeat

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).